# how to scale absolute coordinates libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx to create an android game in which the player can touch a specific part of the screen to move a car left and right on a road. I originally made the game with a height and width of 480 by 800 respectively but when the devices resolution is more or less that what i made it more the touch coordinates are not at the same place. If the a way to scale my coordinates based on the device the game is being played on. The function i use to used calculate the touch points are as followed:

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

        if (inBounds(touchedX, touchedY,0, 585, 120, 140)) {
            taxi.moveLeft();
        }

        else if (inBounds(touchedX, touchedY, 360, 585, 120, 140)) {
            taxi.moveRight();
        }

        else if (inBounds(touchedX, touchedY, 0, 0, 120, 140)) {
            pause();
        }

    }

    if (!Gdx.input.isTouched()) {

        if (inBounds(touchedX, touchedY, 0, 600, 71, 111)) {
            taxi.stopLeft();

        }

        if (inBounds(touchedX, touchedY, 415, 600, 71, 111)) {
            taxi.stopRight();

        }
    }
```

How can I make the coordinates in the inbounds() scale accordingly if the device is larger or smaller than 480 by 800.

Comment: Can you post your `inBounds` and `onResize` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with camera.unproject.

In your touch events do this

```
Vector3 vect=new Vector3(touchedX,touchedY,0);
camera.unproject(vect); // camera is your game camera
float newX=vect.x,newY=vect.y;
if (inBounds(newX, newY, 0, 600, 71, 111)) {
            taxi.stopLeft();

        }
```

This will do the job.

Comment: Ok thanks will give that a try and see if it works out.

Comment: Thanks much it worked. Its fixed. I thought that it was the hard coded values that needed to be scaled. Can you explain to me why it was the touchedX and touchedY instead?

Comment: The touchedx and touchedy values tells you the position of your real screen is. If your screen size is 1280x800, and you click in the bottom right, you'll get the point 1280x800, if you would click in the same spot on a 640x400, you would get the point 640x400 .. when you unproject your coords, they are getting translated for your virtual screen size of the game (viewport)! If i helped you please don't forget to accept my answer and upvote it.